# Guardar entidad que tiene vinculada otras 2 entidades java spring hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, crud

Estoy creando una api rest con Java Spring, estoy usando java-spring-data para el tema de persistencia. Al tratar de guardar un booking (que tiene asociado un member y un facility) me da error.

Me dice que:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el valor null para la columna «facid» viola la restricción not null
  Detail: La fila que falla contiene (7, 10, 2021-03-24 21:30:00, null, null).
```

El hibernate sql:

```
Hibernate: insert into bookings (slots, starttime) values (?, ?)
```

Incluso antes de hacer booking.save hice un systemout para ver que contenia:

```
Booking{bookingId=null, startTime=2021-03-24T21:30, slots=10, facility=Facility{facilityId=1, name='El conuco', memberCost=400.0, guestCost=500.3, initialOutlay=10000.0, monthlyMaintenance=100.0, bookings=[]}, member=Member{memberId=1, surname='apellido', firstname='nombre', address='direccion', zipcode=6001, telephone='04248813351', recommendedBy=null, joinDate=2021-03-23T14:54:52.294, bookings=[]}}
```

La parte donde hago el booking.save es en el servicio (el repositorio extiende CrudRepository), aqui:

```
@Override
    public BookingResponseDTO save(BookingRequestDTO dto) {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        Optional<Member> member = memberRepository.findByID(dto.getMemid());
        Optional<Facility> facility = facilityRepository.findById(dto.getFacid());

        if (member.isPresent() && facility.isPresent()) {
            booking.setMember(member.get());
            booking.setFacility(facility.get());
            booking.setSlots(dto.getSlots());
            booking.setStartTime(dto.getStarttime());

            System.out.println(booking);

            booking = repository.save(booking); // Aqui lanza el error

            return BookingResponseDTO.toDTO(booking);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[image: Modelo]

Este es mi modelo en la base de datos

Esta es mi entidad members

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Member {
    public Member() {
    }

    public Member(String surname, String firstname, String address, Integer zipcode, String telephone, Member recommendedBy, LocalDateTime joinDate) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.address = address;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.recommendedBy = recommendedBy;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "memid")
    private Integer memberId;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "zipcode", nullable = false)
    private Integer zipcode;

    @Column(name = "telephone", nullable = false)
    private String telephone;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="recommendedby")
    private Member recommendedBy;

    @Column(name = "joindate", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime joinDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member")
    private List<Booking> bookings;
    
    // getters y setters
}
```

Esta es mi entidad facility

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "facilities")
public class Facility {
    public Facility() {
    }

    public Facility(String name, Double memberCost, Double guestCost, Double initialOutlay, Double monthlyMaintenance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.memberCost = memberCost;
        this.guestCost = guestCost;
        this.initialOutlay = initialOutlay;
        this.monthlyMaintenance = monthlyMaintenance;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "facid")
    private Integer facilityId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "membercost", nullable = false)
    private Double memberCost;

    @Column(name = "guestcost", nullable = false)
    private Double guestCost;

    @Column(name = "initialoutlay", nullable = false)
    private Double initialOutlay;

    @Column(name = "monthlymaintenance", nullable = false)
    private Double monthlyMaintenance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "facility")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    // getters y setters
}
```

Esta es mi entidad booking

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class Booking {
    public Booking() {
    }

    public Booking(LocalDateTime startTime, Integer slots, Facility facility, Member member) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.slots = slots;
        this.facility = facility;
        this.member = member;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookid")
    private Integer bookingId;

    @Column(name = "starttime", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "slots", nullable = false)
    private Integer slots;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "facid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Facility facility;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "memid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Member member;

    // getters y setters
}
```

Para mas información aquí el repositorio: https://github.com/darioxlz/Bookings-spring

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que mi entidad Booking le faltaban 2 propiedades

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class Booking {
    public Booking() {
    }

    public Booking(LocalDateTime startTime, Integer slots, Facility facility, Member member) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.slots = slots;
        this.facility = facility;
        this.member = member;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookid")
    private Integer bookingId;

    @Column(name = "starttime", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "slots", nullable = false)
    private Integer slots;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "facid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Facility facility;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "memid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Member member;

    @Column(name = "memid")
    private Integer memberId;     // esta

    @Column(name = "facid")
    private Integer facilityId;   // y esta

    // getters y setters
}
```

Y en mi servicio tenia que hacer:

```
@Override
public BookingResponseDTO save(BookingRequestDTO dto) {
    Booking booking = new Booking();
    Optional<Member> member = memberRepository.findByID(dto.getMemid());
    Optional<Facility> facility = facilityRepository.findById(dto.getFacid());

    if (member.isPresent() && facility.isPresent()) {
        booking.setMemberId(member.get().getMemberId());
        booking.setFacilityId(facility.get().getFacilityId);
        booking.setSlots(dto.getSlots());
        booking.setStartTime(dto.getStarttime());

        System.out.println(booking);

        booking = repository.save(booking);

        return BookingResponseDTO.toDTO(booking);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```